# Does slicing a string copy the underlying data?

Tags: string, rust, copy, slice

In Rust, if I wanted read-only access to one `&str` across multiple contexts without copying the *actual* underlying data, am I correct in thinking that I just use a slice?

**Example**

```rust
let original_string = "here's a string";

let slice = &original_string[0..3];
```

Or would something like `Rc<str>` be needed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> read-only access to one &str

you are right, the codes did not copy the string, `&str` basically includes 2 parts, a pointer and a len, thus

```
    let original_string = "here's a string";
    let slice = &original_string[0..3];

    println!("{:?}", original_string.as_ptr());
    println!("{:?}", original_string.len());
    println!("{:?}", slice.as_ptr());
    println!("{:?}", slice.len());
```

The output would look like

```
0x1074d4ee3
15
0x1074d4ee3
3
```

Answer (score 6):

Any reference type `&T` or `&mut T` (including slice types like `&str` or `&[T]`) will only borrow data, and will not implicitly copy or move data when used.

You can explicitly copy from a reference to a type implementing `Copy` by dereferencing it with `*`, or from a reference to a type implementing `Clone` by calling the `clone` method. You can also explicitly move out of a mutable reference by replacing it with a different value, for example with `std::mem::take` or `std::mem::replace`.

Any data that's borrowed by at least one shared reference `&T` must be read only for the lifetime of that reference, except for data inside a container with interior mutability, such as `Cell<T>`, `RefCell<T>`, `Mutex<T>` and `AtomicU32`.

Typically, the biggest limitation of using references is that their lifetime must be shorter than the lifetime of the owner of the data. In some cases, this may make code hard or impossible to express purely with references and lifetimes. Reference-counting pointers like `Rc<T>` and `Arc<T>` can help, as they generally act similar to shared references `&T`, except that instead of borrowing data from some other location, the data is moved into the `Rc`/`Arc` and then the data ownership is shared between all clones of that `Rc`/`Arc`, elimitating the need for reference lifetimes, but at a small runtime cost.

Answer (score 0):

Slicing a string does not copy. Which means you'll have to keep the original string alive as least as long as the slice. (Frxstrem's answer explains this way better.)

`Rc<str>` won't help you, since it must be an `Rc` on the same string or slice, i.e. you can't create a subslice but count references on the same base string with it. If you do absolutely need something like this, you'll have to store an `Rc` on the original string, and the current slice range with it, e.g. like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct SharedString {
    string: Rc<str>,
    slice: Range<usize>,
}

impl Deref for SharedString {
    type Target = str;
    fn deref(&self) -> &str {
        self.string.get(self.slice.clone()).unwrap()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=baa7749486943ac6a782b8141e344ca3)